# grails query to get the average of each day of the week

Tags: grails

I have a grails domain class  which looks something like this :

```
class Answer {
String response
Integer score
Date created = new Date()
}
```

how can i make a query that returns me the average score for each day of the week ? , like this :

```
average for Mondays = 25
average for Tuesdays = 20
....
average for sundays = 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addition to @lucke84's answer, a small modification to his approach (in case my edit to his answer was missed)

```
def summation = [
'monday': [],
'tuesday': [], 
'wednesday': [],
'thursday': [],
'friday': [],
'saturday': [],
'sunday': []
]


def answers = Answer.list() 
answers.each {
    def dateCreated = it.created[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK]

    switch (dateCreated) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            summation.monday << it.score     
            break
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            summation.tuesday << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            summation.wednesday << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            summation.thursday << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            summation.friday << it.score   
            break
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            summation.saturday << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            summation.sunday << it.score
            break
    } ​ 
}

def averages = [:]
averages.monday = (summation['monday'].sum())?.divide(summation['monday'].size())
//So on and So forth.
```

Keep a note that `.list()` would bring back all the rows from `Answer` which might affect performance. In that case you can use `findAll` and pass in `pagination` parameters according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

To get sunday's avg, first get date of sunday.
and then use criteria query to find avg. See example below:

```
dateOfSunday = ..
def c = Answer.createCriteria()
def avgScore = c.get {
  projections {
    avg "score"
  }
 lt("created",dateOfSunday.plus(1) )
 gt("created",dateOfSunday.minus(1) )
}
```

Hope you got the idea...

EDIT:

Ok, If you want all sunday's avg, then you can use formula in your domain class, like:

```
class Answer {
 String response
 Integer score
 Date created = new Date()
 static mapping = {
    dayOfWeek formula: 'DAYOFWEEK(created)'
   }
}
```

And then query would be:

```
def c = Answer.createCriteria()
def avgScore = c.get {
  projections {
    avg "score"
  }
 eq("dayOfWeek ",7)
}
```

EDIT:

@dmahapatro, Thanks for pointing it out.

All avg scores also can be get using single db hit. See below:

```
def results = Answer.createCriteria().list() {
  projections {
    groupProperty('dayOfWeek')
    avg "score"
  }
}
```

Though it involves less code, but it has a drawback, it is using db function which will make the query slow. You can use the suggestion by dmahapatro.

Comment: thanks , but this give the the average of only one day , what i want to do is to get the average of all the saundays in the data base

Comment: But again @Shaful, you will end up with 7 db calls for average. The key is to make that to minimal db calls. :) lucke84 had it almost. A small modification I suggested would make it work to get the average for all the weekdays in one db call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I've got your question and your domain model, but maybe this *draft* could be helpful.

```
def summations = [
    'monday': [],
    'tuesday': [], 
    'wednesday': [],
    'thursday': [],
    'friday': [],
    'saturday': [],
    'sunday': []
]

def answers = Answer.list() 
answers.each {
    def dateCreated = it.created[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK]

    switch (dateCreated) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            summations['monday'] << it.score     
            break
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            summations['tuesday'] << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            summations['wednesday'] << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            summations['thursday'] << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            summations['friday'] << it.score   
            break
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            summations['saturday'] << it.score
            break
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            summations['sunday'] << it.score
            break
    } ​ 
}

// you can now do the average for every list in the map (sum of elements divided by number of item)
```

EDIT:
This is from @dmahapatro:

```
def averages = [:]
averages.monday = (summations['monday'].sum())?.divide(summations['monday'].size())
// So on and So forth.
```

Comment: That is summation, friend. You missed the average part.

Comment: @dmahapatro you're right, mate. Just made a quick change, should be better.